# adding class using jQuery not showing the effects

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, addclass

I have a HTML as below:

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="span7">
          <div class="home-image left-image">
            <img class="photography-left-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x440" />
            <p class="image-text_left">Wedditng Photography</p>
          </div>

          <h5>Heading</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            <div class="home-image right-image right-image-top">
                <img class="photography-right-top" src="http://placehold.it/400x200" />
                <p class="image-text_right-top">Fashion Photography</p>
          </div>
          <div class="home-image right-image right-image-bottom">
            <img class="photography-right-bottom" src="http://placehold.it/400x200" />
            <p class="image-text_right-bottom">Contact</p>
          </div>

          <h5>Heading</h5>
       </div>

      </div>

 </div>
```

And the CSS :

```
.home-image {
    position:relative;
}
.photography-left-top,.photography-right-top,.photography-right-bottom {
    position : absolute;
}
.image-text_left {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    top:200px;;
    left:200px;
    z-index : 100;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.image-text_right-top,.image-text_right-bottom {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    z-index : 100;
    font-weight:bold
}
.right-image-bottom {
    margin-top:220px;
    position:relative
}
.right-top {
    position:relative
}
.home-img-hover {
    background:#911717;
}
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".left-image").hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.photography-left-top').fadeTo('slow',0);
            $(this).addClass('home-img-hover');
            $('.image-text_left').show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).find('.photography-left-top').fadeTo('400',1.0);
            $('.image-text_left').hide();
        });
```

Since `addClass('home-img-hover')` will add the a class to current `class` I was expecting a background color when I hover on `left-image`. But its showing white default background . Why ?

[Sample in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ2bS/)

Comment: .home-img-hover DIV height equal 0

Comment: Because you used .fadeTo('slow', 0); means the item is not visible so you cannot see any styling on the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does exactly what you're expecting, you just can't see it because the `.home-image` doesn't have a height, because everything inside it is taken out of the normal document flow (with `position:absolute`). Try giving `.home-image` some dimensions, and you'll see what I mean:

```
.home-image {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:240px;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ2bS/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem, your div's height is actually `0px`.

Just add

```
height: 240px;
width: 400px;
```

to the `.home-image` class, and you'll see that your code actually works.

See [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ2bS/2/)